# How to specify all H1-H6 headings font properties in one declaration?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

How to specify all H1-H6 headings font properties in one declaration?  A CSSLint.net also show warning that headings should only be defined once. I have a few places where headers specified:

```
h1 { font-size: 1.8em; margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.6em; margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.4em; margin-top: 1.5em; margin-bottom: .5em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 1.2em; margin-bottom: .3em; }
h5 { font-size: 1.1em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: .1em; }
h6 { font-size: 1.0em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: .1em; }

h1, h2 {
padding-bottom:2px;
border-bottom:1px solid #919699;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;
}
```

Comment: It isn't possible using CSS aside from giving all headers a common class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy...  all the site is saying is not to declare the same tags over and over...  use something like this...

```
h1 { font-size: 1.8em; margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em;
padding-bottom:2px;
border-bottom:1px solid #919699;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;}
h2 { font-size: 1.6em; margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: .5em;
padding-bottom:2px;
border-bottom:1px solid #919699;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;}
h3 { font-size: 1.4em; margin-top: 1.5em; margin-bottom: .5em; 
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;}
h4 { font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 1.2em; margin-bottom: .3em;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;}
h5 { font-size: 1.1em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: .1em; 
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;}
h6 { font-size: 1.0em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: .1em;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;}
```

Obviously, your way was slightly more readable...  but this consolidates everything so each tag is only defined once.

Comment: Also...  if you paste that code in to that CSS Line site... you'll see there are no errors / warnings generated.

Comment: A better example of why not to use CSS Lint would be hard to find.

Comment: Some note about third part: `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-weight:bold;
line-height:normal;
}` is this values a default values for headings? If so, can that be omitted?

Comment: @Alohci - I had never actually used CSS Lint before, but I can see instances where keeping all of the code for one tag together would make readability / searchability easier.   I suppose it depends on the markup...

Answer (score 1):

Your example is fine. What they mean is that you should only use an `h1` heading once in your HTML, but that has since changed. The W3C standard now lets you use as many as you want. They actually encourage it, for SEO.

Comment: @Alohci: it will be great if you can suggest another online CSS code analyzer, that can flag duplicate CSS declarations, do syntax check and other useful things.

Comment: @triwo - It's not that CSSLint is specifically bad, it's that the thing that matters most in good CSS authoring is not machine testable - it's how the selectors are used to bind the presentation rules to the *semantics* of the HTML. Tools that report on the things that are machine testable, resulting in advice that undermines those semantic bindings do more harm than good. Finding syntax errors is good of course, but the W3C CSS validator should do that for you.